# How to resolve 431 error - return base 64 from nitro server to frontend

Tags: javascript, base64, http-error, nuxtjs3

I'm currently working on a project to learn more about Nuxt 3.

I am transforming an image on the server side and want to return a base 64 string back to the client:

```js
// server/api/image.js
import imageToBase64 from 'image-to-base64'
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const param = useQuery(event)
  const url = 'https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/' + param.query + '/' + param.query + '~thumb.jpg'
  return await imageToBase64(url)
    .then(response => {
        return response // base 64
      })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
})
```

```js
// test.vue
const base64 = await $fetch(`/api/image?query=${el.id}`)
```

But I got an `431` error and don't know the right approach to fix the problem.

> GET http://localhost:3000/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/wAALCAIAAoABAREA/8QAHwAAAQUBACQoL/ [...]
> [HTTP/1.1 431 Request Header Fields Too Large 0ms]

Do you have any ideas? I only read about to clearing my browser cache...

Comment: I think you are missing the prefix of the data URI (protocol, mime type, encoding), so the browser thinks the string is supposed to be a relative URL.

Comment: @CherryDT - how is that relevant to `Request Header Fields Too Large`

Comment: I would add the prefix on the `<img>` tag @CherryDT, but you're right it has to be done.

Comment: use a POST for such large data - how long is your URL string if it's a base64 encoded image!

Comment: @Bravo: It's relevant because currently it's not a data URI but a relative path, so it will attempt to load the image from `http://localhost:3000/9j/<huge string here>` which not only won't deliver an image but also will cause 431 because the path is far too long. It's supposed to be `data:image/png;base64,<huge string here>` which would be fine.

Comment: @Bravo: That's not the case here, the OP didn't even intend to send such an HTTP request in the first place. It seems the base64 string was put into the `src` of an image tag as is, which results in this misrepresentation.

Comment: @CherryDT - how do you know what the OP intended? I don't presume to know

Comment: @CherryDT - it works to render the images, when I add the prefix on the server side. Thanks!

Comment: are you deliberately using an URL that is 1000's of characters long? if so, *you're doing coding wrong™*

Comment: Why I know: because it's obvious from the code, the error and the question. They are requesting the base64 data from the server, the code for that is shown, and it's working because the data shows up in the error and the error URL does not match the initial request URL. Instead, the error matches what happens when you try to set this as source of an image without correct prefix. And no, coding is not done wrong here, data URIs are a valid thing and can have hundreds of thousands of characters.